# Emissive light source does not affect shading of other objects Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm working on a solar system project that involves planets and a rocketship orbiting around a sun. There is currently a main light source with the code being as follows

```
// add subtle ambient lighting
var ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x0c0c0c);
scene.add(ambientLight);

// add spotlight for the shadows
var spotLight = new THREE.PointLight(0xffffff);
spotLight.position.set(-200, 50, 150);
spotLight.castShadow = true;
scene.add(spotLight);
```

I have created a sun object and tried giving it an emissive property so that it can shine light at other planets too. Although it seems to make the planet glow in a sense, it's more of just the object lighting up and not having shading rather than actually becoming a light source. The code for the sun object is as follows

```
 function createSunMesh(geom) {
     var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
     var planetSunTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/sun.jpg");
     //var normalSunTexture = loader.load("../assets/textures/planets/moonbump.jpg");

     var planetSunMaterial = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({map: planetSunTexture, emissive: 0xac3d25});
     //bumpMap: normalMoonTexture

     // create a multimaterial
     var planetSunMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geom, [planetSunMaterial]);
     planetSunMesh.visible = false;

     return planetSunMesh;
 }
```

So my question is, is there a way to make the emissive property of the light stronger / strong enough to impact the other objects? I have tried using both Lambert / Phong materials but they seem to have the same effect as one another.

Comment: you are talking about light interactions between objects in the scene and three.js doesnt support that out of the box. you can see an example at `webgl_raymarching_reflect.html` but you would have to implement this (or similar algorithms) yourself.

Comment: @gaitat Would such a feature be hard to implement?

Comment: light interactions is not considered an easy feature to implement. there are many algorithms to follow. if you limit the scope of the problem then it might become tractable.

Comment: @gaitat in that case, would it be possible to completely remove the spot light so that all objects would be equally lit? because currently my light is only being sent from one direction which makes some of my models much harder to see

Comment: i have not seen your application, I dont know what it does and I dont know what you want to achieve; basically, this is you decision.

Comment: @gaitat basically is there a way to make the whole scene equally lit? so shadows wouldn't exist as such?

Comment: I am sorry I dont understand what `equally lit` means. Maybe if you use `MeshBasicMaterial` and turn off lights you will get what you want?

Comment: @gaitat I actually figured out how to do what I wanted. I just changed the position of my spotlight and put it inside the sun, so it looks like the sun is lighting up the other planets. 

Do you know of a way that I can make the spotlight stronger?

Comment: increase `intensity` reduce `decay`

Comment: @gaitat perfect, this is all sorted then :D thank you for your suggestions and support

Answer (score 1):

I ended up repositioning the main spotlight so it was within my sun object, which gave it the same effect that I was looking for. Also, I increased the intensity and reduced the decay to give the light a more realistic effect